# Try to send value of input to function [Angular with mat-select (Material)]

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

Hey i have form in my project and i try to send to value of mat-select

my html:

```
  <mat-form-field class="input-class" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>בחר שותף <i class="far fa-id-card"></i></mat-label>
            <mat-select placeholder="בחר שותף">
                <mat-option value="partner" #partnerValue *ngFor="let partner of partnersData">{{partner}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
   <div class="col-sm">
        <button class="aproveBtn" (click)="submitForm(partnerValue)">Create</button>
    </div>
```

my ts file:

```
  submitForm(partner) {
    console.log(partner);
  }
```

its console undefiend or error what is the problem??

Comment: `<mat-select #partnerValue placeholder="בחר שותף">` & `(click)="submitForm(partnerValue.value)"`

Comment: we have `[(value)]` to get the two way binding

Comment: Its not work, it console "partner" and not the original value that selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angulars two way binding:

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="selectedPartner">
...
 <button class="aproveBtn" (click)="submitForm(selectedPartner)">Create</button>
```

Have a look at the [angular materials select API](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) for more [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples).

A [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xnldkjeqeqn?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) from the docs which uses 2-way value binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your html file as-

```
<mat-form-field class="input-class" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>בחר שותף <i class="far fa-id-card"></i></mat-label>
            <mat-select #partnerValue placeholder="בחר שותף">
                <mat-option [value]="partner"  *ngFor="let partner of partnersData">{{partner}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
   <div class="col-sm">
        <button class="aproveBtn" (click)="submitForm(partnerValue.value)">Create</button>
    </div>
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag9ken).